# value in list of list changes

Tags: java, list

I am confused about the java list:

```
public static void testListValueChange() {
    List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<Integer>> tt = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    int a = 1;
    t.add(a);
    tt.add(t);
    System.out.println(tt);
    t.add(2);
    System.out.println(tt);

}
```

why did my second printing print `[[1,2]]`? I just added res when res = [1]

Comment: `tt` has an element which is a reference to `t`, which you inserted 1 and 2 into.

Comment: if i want to avoid this. is there any solution?

Comment: Make a copy of `t` when adding it to `tt`

Comment: @SihanWang just do `tt.add(new ArrayList<>(t));` instead to make a copy and get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `List.add` does add a pointer to your object (reference), and does NOT copy the object and then add the copy. That's the normal behaviour in Java when working with objects, it's different when you are using primitives (here it'll work with copys, not with pointers/references).

Here you can see the same behaviour:

```
public class MyClass {
  int a;
}

public void a() {
  MyClass x = new MyClass(); // "x" is an object
  x.a = 1;
  b(x); // <- it calls method "b" with a reference/pointer to "MyClass x"
  System.out.println(x.a); // <- prints 2
}

public void b(MyClass x) {
  x.a = 2;
}
```

and with primitives:

```
public void a() {
  int x = 1; // "x" is a primitive
  b(x); // <- it calls method "b" with a copy of "int x"
  System.out.println(x); // <- prints 1
}

public void b(int x) {
  x = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tt` has one element, which points to `t`. When you modify `t`, you'r also modifying the first (and only) element of `tt`. As you can see, `t` has two values: 1 and 2.